# Redux : combineReducers

Tags: redux

while using combineReducers getting error :

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {todos, counter}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Following is the code :

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import counter from "./reducers/counter";
import todos from "./reducers/todos";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  todos,
  counter
});

export default createStore(reducer);
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are you using `createStore(reducer)` in your React application?

Comment: without using combine reducers works fine

Comment: It seems that somewhere else in your code you are trying to render your reducers. The issue doesn't appear to be with this code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line `{this.props.count}` (once again, please add this to the question, not as an answer). Here you are attempting to render the entire state object you mapped from redux, causing the error.

Since you changed the `state` to include two reducers instead of just one as before, doing `count: state` isn't the same anymore.
I'm guessing you are intending to render the count from the counter reducer.

You'll need to change how you access it. I would recommend changing your `mapStateToProps` function.

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  count: state.counter,
  todos: state.todos
});
```

Then to render the count, do this:

```js
<Text style={styles.counter} onPress={this.props.reset}>
  {this.props.count}
</Text>
```